# OpenCV cmake building always throwing error in Windows

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to build this [GitHub lib][1]. I created a new build folder which inside I tried `cmake ..` check attached screenshots. I am always getting this error:

```
>-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>See also "C:/Users/Desktop/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>See also "C:/Users/Desktop/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Files found [here][5]

Comment: It may help if you attached this file "C:/Users/Desktop/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Comment: `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: adding files now

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov what is that command like code?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef can u take a look at that uploaded file?

Comment: You are missing files from related repositories (aka submodules). Execute the command in your source folder to fetch them

Comment: ok doing now ....

Comment: i executed that command but it didnt show any files updating or adding, after few seconds it moved to new prompt

Comment: you should execute it in the same folder where your `.git` folder lives

Comment: now it cloning into all the sub modules

Comment: CMake Warning at opencv/download/opencv-2.4.13.6/cmake/OpenCVPackaging.cmake:23 (message):
  CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION does not match version provided by version.hpp
  header!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  opencv/download/opencv-2.4.13.6/CMakeLists.txt:1103 (include)


Warning: use default build number of 0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/PNaveen/Desktop/nfiq/gitrepo/NFIQ2/build

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov to get a dll file should i run that .sln and build ?

Comment: you should consult [readme file](https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2/blob/iso_wg3/README.md) of your project on that matters, but basically yes

Comment: hi, LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\opencv-2.4.13.6\3rdparty\lib\Release\zlib.lib' always getting this error but i can see that zlib file in path nay solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alexey Andronov said, you have to download [this](https://github.com/kerukuro/digestpp/tree/36fa6ca2b85808bd171b13b65a345130dbe1d774) to your **digestpp** folder, and [this](https://github.com/FingerJetFXOSE/FingerJetFXOSE/tree/ad7b78db725bfca75657897a11071bc35906c96b) to your **fingerjetfxose** folder, also inside the last one, download [this](https://github.com/CxxTest/cxxtest/tree/48bf84df8a84794cbc3919281f7f95663db9217a) to your **fingerjetfxose/cxxtest** folder.